# What do these distance numbers mean?

Tags: qgis, python, vector, distance, road

In the picture below, the red line is State Hwy 15, while the lake in the picture is Sooner lake. Please note that the highway intersects the lake several times and is very close to it at a number of points. However the code returns the following distance values from State Hwy 15 to Sooner Lake (reformated here of course).

Sooner Lake - State Hwy 15: 1485956.665928024

Sooner Lake - State Hwy 15: 1485956.733344301

These distance values are too big to be meters, km, inches or feet, so I don't understand what the units are for the values. Since they are all > 20, which is the max_distance set in the code, they are rejected.

I have no idea what is happening here. Yes, much of the code is commented out, as I just needed to get some values to start with.

Help!

[image]

```
from collections import defaultdict
import networkx as nx
from itertools import product

roadlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('testroads')[0] #Change to match your road layer name
lakelyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('test')[0] #Same
exroadlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('roads_explode_lines')[0] #The road layer after "Explode lines" processing tool
max_distance = 20 #From lake to road

roadlyr.selectAll()
lakelyr.selectAll()
exroadlyr.selectAll()

print(roadlyr)
print(lakelyr)
print(exroadlyr)
print(max_distance)

print('lakelyr')
selection = lakelyr.selectedFeatures()
#print(selection)
print(len(selection))

print('roadlyr')
selection2 = roadlyr.selectedFeatures()
#print(selection2)
print(len(selection2))

print('exroadlyr')

selection3 = exroadlyr.selectedFeatures()
#print(selection3)
print(len(selection3))



#FIND NEARBY ROADS AND EACH ROAD SINGLE CLOSEST VERTEX
d = defaultdict(list)
for lake in lakelyr.getFeatures():
#    print(lake.geometry())
    for road in roadlyr.getFeatures():
        if lake['Name'] == 'Sooner Lake':
            if road['FULLNAME'] == 'State Hwy 15':
                print(lake['Name'])
                print(road['FULLNAME'])
                print(lake.geometry().distance(road.geometry()))
#        print(lake.geometry().distance(road.geometry()))
#        print(road)
        if lake.geometry().distance(road.geometry())<=max_distance or lake.geometry().intersects(road.geometry()):
            print('true')
            d[lake].append(road)
#
#start_and_ends = [] #This is the result holding all start and end vertices
#for lake, roads in d.items():
#    #print(lake,road)
#    temp_vertlist = []
#    for road in roads:
#        vertlist = [v for v in road.geometry().vertices()]
#        closest_vertice = min(vertlist, key=lambda x: lake.geometry().distance(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(x))))
#        #temp_vertlist.append(closest_vertice)
#        temp_vertlist.append((round(closest_vertice.x()),round(closest_vertice.y())))
#    start_and_ends.append(temp_vertlist)
#
##CREATE A NETWORKX GRAPH
#G = nx.Graph()
#for feat in exroadlyr.getFeatures():
#    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104610/fastest-way-to-get-the-first-and-last-element-of-a-python-iterator
#    g = feat.geometry()
#    first = last = next(g.vertices())
#    for last in g.vertices():
#        pass
#    first = (round(first.x()), round(first.y()))
#    last = (round(last.x()), round(last.y()))
#    roadlength = round(g.length(),0)
#    G.add_edge(first, last, weight=roadlength, lineid=feat.id(), linegeom=feat.geometry())
#
#paths = []
#for start, end in product(start_and_ends[0], start_and_ends[1]):
#    try:
#        p = (nx.dijkstra_path(G, start, end, weight='weight'))
#        paths.append(p)
#    except:
#        pass
#
##Create a line layer for all paths
#vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs={}&index=yes".format(roadlyr.crs().authid()), "all_paths", "memory")
#provider = vl.dataProvider()
#for p in paths:
#    gLine = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(x,y) for x,y in p])
#    f = QgsFeature()
#    f.setGeometry(gLine)
#    provider.addFeature(f)
#QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
#
##Select shortest path
#all_paths = [f for f in vl.getFeatures()]
#shortest_path = min(all_paths, key=lambda x: x.geometry().length())
#vl.select(shortest_path.id())
#
#print('Done')
```

Comment: What CRS is the road layer in? Perhaps they are digital degrees?

Comment: The road layer is:  CRS EPSG:4269 - NAD83 - Geographic
The lake layer is:   CRS EPSG:5070 - NAD83 / Conus Albers - Projected
The road exploded layer is:  CRS EPSG:4269 - NAD83 - Geographic